# Finding a way to check whether a file has been rotated

Tags: linux, ext4, inode

In one of my projects which involves searching into logfiles on Linux, I need to find out how to check whether a logfile has been rotated, usually using the logrotate Linux utility.

Due to legacy Linux kernels level constraint, I can't use the `statx stx_btime` filesystem because it's only available since kernel 4.11. The used filesystem is `ext4`.

`inode` and `dev` IDs seem to be a good option, but I found out the `inode` can be reused or not in case of a file is rotated and re-created using the same name. I tested it on `ext4, btrfs, xfs` filesystems by creating a file, zipping it, re-creating with different data inside but with the same name. `inode` is the same each time.

I can imagine a cross-platform algorithm to manage this but can someone confirm this behaviour ?

Thanks for any hint !

Comment: I'd be interested to understand some more about your need to know if a logfile has been rotated. For example, typically a logfile would be suffixed with `.1` or a date string, and possibly compressed. Can't you just check for those?

Comment: It's not generic enough and not portable across platforms.

Comment: If you're looking at portability across platforms then considering `statx` is a non starter. I'm trying to help you out here

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can manage portability with conditional compilation. But i can't just rely on existence on .1 file

Comment: So explain a little more about the need to know if a logfile has been rotated. There may be a different solution